# Firebase User Authentication not working properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm still very new at this so apologize for any minor mistake I made

I'm trying to learn how to make a login system with email and password using Firebase but it doesn't seem to work as intended. The code to check whether the email is empty, incorrect format, password length not matching the parameter is not working too. I double check my code before running and I'm not getting any result.

I already connect this app to Firebase and add Firebase Authentication SDK

[Clicking the login button will not make any error as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtRnj.png)

**loginPage.kt**

```
class loginPage : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var binding : LoginPageBinding
lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding = LoginPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page)

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    login_back_button.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener{
        val email = binding.emailField.text.toString()
        val password = binding.passwordField.text.toString()

        if (email.isEmpty()){
            binding.emailField.error = "Email cannot be empty"
            binding.emailField.requestFocus()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            binding.emailField.error = "Email not valid"
            binding.emailField.requestFocus()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }

        if (password.length > 6){
            binding.passwordField.error = "Minimal password length is 6"
            binding.passwordField.requestFocus()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        RegisterFirebase(email,password)
    }
}

private fun RegisterFirebase(email: String, password: String) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this){
            if (it.isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Register Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(this, homePage::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "${it.exception?.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}
```

}

**homePage.kt**

```
class homePage : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    setContentView(R.layout.home_page)
}
```

}

**EditText for entering email (in login_page.xml)**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email_field"
    android:layout_width="272dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:background="@drawable/email_password_filler"
    android:hint="@string/enter_your_email"
    android:paddingStart="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="5sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.126"
    tools:ignore="Autofill,RtlSymmetry,TextFields" />
```

**For entering password (in login_page.xml)**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password_field"
    android:layout_width="272dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:background="@drawable/email_password_filler"
    android:hint="@string/enter_your_password"
    android:paddingStart="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="5sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.208"
    tools:ignore="Autofill,RtlSymmetry,TextFields" />
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password should always be greater than or equal to 6 and in your case, the condition is opposite. Fix it like this:

```
if (password.length < 6) {
    binding.passwordField.error = "Minimal password length is 6"
    binding.passwordField.requestFocus()
    return@setOnClickListener
}
```

`login_back_button` is missing `binding` reference as well as if it's a back button then you should just use `finish` to go back to previous activity rather than creating new instance again. Like this:

```
binding.loginBackButton.setOnClickListener { finish() }
```

**Update:**

The issue is that you are using `binding` but not passing it in `setContentView`. Fix it like this:

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: Thanks for the password fix, I have edited my code but still not getting the error

Comment: Try `log.d` before `email` variable in the `onClickListener` to check whether it's being pressed or not.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try it now! @FlipCats

Comment: the setContentView fixed it, thank you so much for your help

Comment: glad it worked, you can accept the answer now :) @FlipCats